# How to binding `ngx-intl-tel-input` with only "internationalNumber"

Tags: angular7, model-binding

I'm use ngx-intl-tel-input, when binding have model with:

```
"phone":
{
   "countryCode": "",
   "dialCode": "",
   "internationalNumber": "",
   "nationalNumber": "",
   "number": ""
}
```

but I want model:

```
"phone":
{
   "internationalNumber": ""
}
```

what can I do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can have middleware variable for the binding :

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input  [(ngModel)]="mobile"> <ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

for example:-

```
let mobile;
let internationalNumber="";
internationalNumber=mobile.internationalNumber;
```

now your binding is ready!

Answer (score 1):

`[(ngModel)]` actually comes with event binding and property binding. Below two lines are equal.

```
<input [ngModel]="yourVariable" (ngModelChange)="yourVariable = $event">
```

and

```
<input [(ngModel)]="yourVariable">
```

So for your question, you can do something like below.

```
<input [ngModel]="yourVariable" (ngModelChange)="yourVariable = $event.internationalNumber">
```

Comment: Assuming you're using reactive forms, how do you accomplish the same thing?